# react-native and react-navigation: Accesing params from sibling screen in TabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am accessing params in a screen in a TabNavigator from another screen in the same TabNavigator.

This is how I am currently doing it:

```
const siblingNavigator = props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getChildNavigation('Cities');
const data = siblingNavigator.getParam('data');
```

This seems very convoluted, and potentially buggy.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the required data to the `screenProps`. I don't know what kind of bug the function I'm using now, but I haven't seen it while I'm using it.

```js
const SomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  // config
});
<SomeStack
  screenProps={/* this prop will get passed to the screen components as this.props.screenProps */}
/>
```

**Example**

```js
const SomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  // config
});
...
class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: "somedata"};
  }

  render() {
    return(<SomeStack screenProps={{ data: this.state.data}} />
  }
}
```

// Now you can do in your screens

```
console.log(this.props.screenProps.data);
```